# Javascript: How to convert dec byte array object into hex string?

Tags: javascript

So i have an object, 
    type "Buffer",
    data is array of [0,0,2,6,116].

If treat this array as decimals, i want to convert into hex string.
0, 0, 2, 6, 116 => 0, 0, 2, 6, 74 => 00, 00, 02, 06, 74

Eventually i want to see 20674 or 0000020674 in the webpage.

What's the fastest way/build-in function in Javascript please ?

Comment: `input.map(function(a){return ("0"+a.toString(16)).slice(-2);})`

Comment: please don't add tags like [tag:angularjs] just because the library is in use somewhere in your project.  Add tags when they have context meaningful to the question.

Comment: Niet, it worked, thanks ! I'm surprised there's no buldin js function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String concatenation might be expensive depending of the size of your buffer. So the quickest way is probably to encode the data and use `String.fromCharCode` to build the string :

```
function dataToString(data){
  var buffer = [], table = [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,65,66,67,68,69,70];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
    buffer.push(table[data[i] >> 4]); 
    buffer.push(table[data[i] & 15]);
  }

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, buffer);
}

dataToString([0,0,2,6,116]);
```

Or with string concatenation:

```
[0,0,2,6,116].map(v => "0123456789ABCDEF"[v >> 4] + "0123456789ABCDEF"[v & 15]).join('');
```